# Getting python 3+ comparison on return value and inputted value

Tags: python, string-comparison

Its been several months since I have worked with python. Im not getting an error, but im also not receiving the desired output too.

I have a function:

```
def set_account(gather_accounts):
    print("gather_accounts():\n")
    for a in gather_accounts:
        print('Value: {}'.format(a[1]))

    if decision_enter_account == 'Y':
        bool_add_account = True
        while bool_add_account == True:

            prompt_account_url  = input('What is the account\'s url?\n')
            prompt_account_name = input('\nWhat is the account name? \n')
            #TODO check for duplicate account names, and disallow
            for a in gather_accounts:
                if prompt_account_name == a[1]:
                    print('Sorry you already had an account with {} try again.\n'.format(prompt_account_name))
                    prompt_account_name = input('\nWhat is the account name? \n')
```

Im trying to implement a check for duplicates against the return value `gather_accounts`, specifically, in a `for` loop `a[1]` gets a value like `Chase`

However, when i run this script if I enter in `Chase` it doesnt hit: `if prompt_account_name == a[1]`

How can i fix this to compare the user inputted value of `prompt_account_name` and compare it to the value in `a[1]`?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Is `gather_accounts` a list of tuples of two strings?

Comment: That snippet works fine for me. Can you show how are you creating gather_accounts and what version of Python are your running?

Comment: running python3+, gather_accounts is a return value from another function

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are running in Python2, If in Python2, you need to use `prompt_account_name = raw_input('\nWhat is the account name? \n')` instead of `prompt_account_name = input('\nWhat is the account name? \n')` in this case.

Actually, in Python3, the `input()` is equivalent to `raw_input()` in Python2. 
While the `raw_input()` is removed in Python3.

Comment: It is definitely Python3

Comment: If OP was using 2.7, I'd expect him to get an exception `NameError: name 'Chase' is not defined`. But he says he's not getting an error.